Flutter - Way to design a Container with strange borderRadius
I need some help with building a user interface for my app. While browsing Dribbble, I came across a design that I think would be simple and fast to replicate. However, I'm struggling with creating a Container that has a unique borderRadius in Flutter.
Here's a link to the design:

I plan to add a black appBar with a leading and actions for the two icons and then create a Container in the body. However, I can't seem to figure out how to achieve the non-standard borderRadius on the bottom right corner.
Can you please help me with this? Thank you in advance for your assistance.

After reviewing your responses, I found this code to be the easiest to reproduce and fit the design I wanted.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gap/gap.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:ui_blackandwhite/components/course_card.dart';
import 'package:ui_blackandwhite/components/langage_card.dart';
import 'package:ui_blackandwhite/components/my_search_bar.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        leading: const Icon(
          Icons.menu_rounded,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 30,
        ),
        actions: const [
          Icon(
            Icons.person,
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 30,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          // Barre de recherche
          Container(
            height: 100,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: const Center(child: MySearchBar()),
          ),

          // Reste de la page
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black,
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(50.0),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 50.0,
                    left: 25.0,
                    right: 25.0,
                    bottom: 25.0,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      // Texte "recommendé pour vous"
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text(
                          "Recommendé pour vous",
                          style: GoogleFonts.kanit(
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                      const Gap(15.0),

                      // List View de quelques langages de programmations
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 100,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return const LangageCard();
                          },
                        ),
                      ),

                      const Gap(75),

                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text(
                          "Dernières formations vues",
                          style: GoogleFonts.kanit(
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                      const Gap(15.0),

                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView(
                          children: const [
                            CourseCard(title: "Front-End"),
                            CourseCard(title: "Back-End"),
                            CourseCard(title: "JavaScript"),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

I created a container within another container, giving them different border-radius and colors.

There are multiple ways to achieve this. One would be with a CustomClipper but I think the same effect can be obtained using a Stack and widgets for the corners with a simple border radius.
https://dartpad.dev/?id=51c04550077960bdad72c0b3bf5063c9
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: TestPage(),
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const borderRadius = 48.0;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              Positioned(
                bottom: -borderRadius,
                left: 0,
                child: Container(
                  height: borderRadius * 2,
                  width: borderRadius * 2,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: -borderRadius,
                right: 0,
                child: Container(
                  height: borderRadius * 2,
                  width: borderRadius * 2,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


I posted how I finally reproduced the design in my answer, check it out, I think it's easier to reproduce as a beginner.

I have achieved this similar feature while developing 'message box' in my chatting application. This is how I created curviness from one side of a container.
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black, // I put black here for you
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
          topRight: Radius.circular(20),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(1),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // Add your widgets here
        ],
      ),
    ),


You're answer is probably not working cause if you look back at the design I want, the bottom right corner has a "negative radius".

There are several approaches to achieve this. Here's one way to do it:
CustomClipper is a powerful tool in Flutter for creating shapes. Here in another file, You can define a CustomClipper class that extends CustomClipper<Path> to create a curved shape. Then, apply this CustomClipper to the AppBar to achieve the desired curved effect.
AppBar:
appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(150),
    child: ClipPath(
      clipper: CurveAppBar(),
      child: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        leading: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white),
        actions: [
          Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),

CustomClipper file:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CurveAppBar extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - 50);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width / 5, size.height / 2.5, size.width / 2, size.height - 50);//Adjust Your curves here
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width * 3 / 4, size.height, size.width, size.height - 50);//Adjust your curves here
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}

Feel free to adjust the parameters of the CustomClipper to customize the curves according to your specific design.

I posted how I finally reproduced the design in my answer, check it out, I think it's easier to reproduce as a beginner.

Implement a custom BoxBorder
BoxBorder is used with the Flutter Container's BoxDecoration, so writing a custom implementation compliments this API, and lets you neatly control the edge inset dimensions so child Widgets are aligned properly, and overall a custom BoxBorder is flexible for which designs it supports, since it uses a canvas to draw the shape to the screen, only mathematics is the limit.
class ChatBubbleBorder extends BoxBorder {
  final double borderWidth;
  final Radius radius;

  const ChatBubbleBorder(
      {this.borderWidth = 2, this.radius = const Radius.circular(16)});

  @override
  void paint(
    Canvas canvas,
    Rect rect, {
    TextDirection? textDirection,
    BoxShape shape = BoxShape.rectangle,
    BorderRadius? borderRadius,
  }) {
    var paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.yellow;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    var modifiedRect =
        Rect.fromLTWH(rect.left, rect.top, rect.width, rect.height - radius.y);

    RRect rRect = RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
      modifiedRect,
      bottomLeft: radius,
      topLeft: radius,
      topRight: radius,
      bottomRight: Radius.zero,
    );
    canvas.drawRRect(rRect, paint);

    var path = Path();
    path.moveTo(rect.width - radius.x, rect.height - radius.y);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        rect.width, rect.height - radius.y, rect.width, rect.height);
    path.lineTo(rect.width, rect.height - radius.y);
    path.close();
    // In case of margin move the path.
    path = path.shift(rect.topLeft);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  BorderSide get top => BorderSide(width: borderWidth);

  @override
  BorderSide get bottom => BorderSide(width: borderWidth + radius.y);

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
        borderWidth,
        borderWidth,
        borderWidth,
        borderWidth + radius.y,
      );

  @override
  bool get isUniform => false;

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => ChatBubbleBorder(
        borderWidth: t * borderWidth,
        radius: Radius.circular(t * radius.y),
      );
}

Usage and result
Here a scroll view is passed as a child to the container using the custom ChatBubbleBorder, this shows that the content is rendered within the expected dimensions.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(home: BorderTestScreen()));

class BorderTestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const BorderTestScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          border: ChatBubbleBorder(),
        ),
        child: const SizedBox(
          width: 300,
          height: 100,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Text(
              "Testing1\nTesting2\nTesting3\nTesting4\nTesting5\nTesting6",
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



I posted how I finally reproduced the design in my answer, check it out, I think it's easier to reproduce as a beginner.
